# Haml complex nest

Tags: haml, nested

I have read some simple nesting way in haml, however when the nesting get complex i feel very lost.

in wanna write something like this in haml, but i keep failing

```
<p><div id="icon"></div>Subject: <span id="new_color">item name</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%p
  #icon
  Subject:&nbsp;
  %span#new_color
    item name
```

Comment: Not really. What you wrote in html is
<p></p>
<div id="icon"></div>
Subject:
<span id="new_color">item name</span>
<p></p>

Comment: It is not surprising if you check it using some sort of a browser developer tools (say, Chrome DT or FireBug). Since your markup is not valid, your browser made it valid for you. Please, check source code of the page or use online HAML converter (e.g., [w2tags](http://w2tags.heroku.com/)).